# vim: goto to insert mode after :write

Tags: vim

I want to return to insert mode after writing (see: `else`)

```
function! SaveOrSaveAsInInsert()
  if @% == ""
    :browse saveas
  else
    :w     
    "//TODO: Return to insert mode
  endif
endfunction
```

Tried with `:w<CR>a` but does not work.

Thanks!

**Edit**

@Randy Morris, commented using `startinsert` which works.  On the other hand `:h inserting-ex` says:

> NOTE: These commands cannot be used
>   with |:global| or |:vglobal|.
>   ":append" and ":insert" don't work
>   properly in between ":if" and
>   ":endif", ":for" and ":endfor",
>   ":while" and ":endwhile".

So my question is am I stuck with `startinsert` `i` equivalent, or is there a way to get around with an `a` behavior? Or should I stick with `imap <C-s>  <Esc>w<CR>a` and no filename testing?

Comment: I believe you want `startinsert` but I can't test at the moment.

Comment: Yes, please write it as an anwser. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inoremap <expr> <c-s> "\<esc>:" . (@% == "" ? "browse saveas" : "w") . "\<cr>gi"`

I use `gi` to get back to insert mode. And use an expression mapping to determine if the file has been saved or not.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this in my .vimrc so that ctrl-s saves and returns to what ever mode I was in previously. It might help you figure it out. ;-)

```
" Use CTRL-S for saving, also in Insert mode
noremap <C-S> :update<CR>
vnoremap <C-S> <C-C>:update<CR>
inoremap <C-S> <C-O>:update<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by

```
:inoremap <silent> <C-S> 
   <Esc>:if expand("%") == ""<CR>:browse saveas<CR>:else<CR>:w<CR>:endif<CR>a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a pseudo-noop mapping that will work for all modes:

```
function s:Save()
    update
    return ""
endfunction
inoremap <expr> <C-s> <SID>Save()
nnoremap <expr> <C-s> <SID>Save()
<...>
```